# Core Data (Magical Record) disconnect entity from data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

In the view did load of a table controller I have the following

```
ButtonList = [Buttons MR_findAllSortedBy:@"listOrder" ascending:YES];
```

This is never called again, but evidently the data source that this is connected to does change int he background, which somehow propagates to the button list entity even though there is no new fetch.  Is there a way to "unbind" this list after the initial call?

Comment: You might want to create a disconnected `Buttons` in a nil context, then copy across the values from the connected `Buttons` to the disconnected `Buttons`. I am doing the copying across part by using `initWithCoder` for reasons of maintainability. It's a bit of code, though.

Comment: Could you show an example of the buttons nil reference?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to

1. make sure you save other changes
2. nil your local references to
   the results
3. refetch with this same fetch request.

Core Data doesn't do this automatically for you. For something more automatic, look at NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: Can you show me a code example of setting the entity to nil for the local reference?